# convert a time to unix time in CPP

Tags: c++, qt, unix, time, window

This is very old question and there are similar topics to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000710/c-how-can-i-convert-a-date-in-year-month-day-format-to-a-unix-epoch-format) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689565/convert-unix-time-to-utc-datetime) and so on. I have:

- **year** like **2014**,
- ### **month** like **10**,
- ...
- **seconds** like **23**.

Using these **integers** I want to get the **unix time** (the seconds since 1970. 01. 01.). But finally I want only an **integer** again. How can I do that?

I can use only **STL** and **QT** (not Boost). I know there is QDateTime which can solve this, but I still don't know how.

**EDIT1:**
I tried this one, but it seems something went wrong:

```
const WCCIL::QDate dd(/*fill it*/);
const WCCIL::QTime tt(/*fill it*/);
WCCIL::QDateTime ddtt( dd, tt); // error, no constructor
ddtt.toUTC();
```

Comment: And why the posted answers in the link does not satisfy you ?

Answer (score 1):

The first link you posted ([C++ How can I convert a date in year-month-day format to a unix epoch format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000710/c-how-can-i-convert-a-date-in-year-month-day-format-to-a-unix-epoch-format)) contains the answer you want. You need to use a `tm` struct with `mktime()`. See the [`mktime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime) man page for more information.